# Java DOM parser to filter out SOAP namespace-prefixes?

Tags: java, dom, soap

I am parsing a SOAP that has elements with namespace-prefixed names:

```
<ns1:equipmentType>G</ns1:equipmentType>
```

So the parser faithfully creates elements with namespace-prefixed names:

```
ns1:equipmentType
```

Can I somehow tell the parser to filter out all the namespace-prefixes? so the element names will be like:

```
equipmentType
```

My code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
```

Comment: Why do you need them without the namespace prefix? XPath expressions?  The removal of the namespaces may cause some ambiguity...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t see that you set the parser to be namespace-aware so that’s most probably the missing thing here.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
```

Then invoking `getLocalName()` on a node will give you the name without any prefix.

However if that’s not enough for you and you really want to get rid of the name-spaces at all you can use an XML transformation to create a new DOM tree without the name-spaces:

```
Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(
  new StreamSource(new StringReader("<?xml version='1.0'?>"
   +"<stylesheet xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>"
   +  "<template match='*' priority='1'>"
   +    "<element name='{local-name()}'><apply-templates select='@*|node()'/></element>"
   +  "</template>"
   +  "<template match='@*' priority='0'>"
   +    "<attribute name='{local-name()}'><value-of select='.'/></attribute>"
   +  "</template>"
   +  "<template match='node()' priority='-1'>"
   +    "<copy><apply-templates select='@*|node()'/></copy>"
   +  "</template>"
   +"</stylesheet>")));
DOMResult result=new DOMResult();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), result);
document=(Document)result.getNode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to do `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

On the resulting Document instance you can then use `getLocalName()` to get element names without the prefix.

You can also use for example `getElementsByTagNameNS()` where you provide the namespace URI and the local tag name to find the elements you need. This decouples your code from the actual prefix that is being used for that namespace inside that particular document. I'm thinking this is actually what you're after.

Comment: setNamespaceAware and getLocalName seems to work (but Holger was the first so he got the bounty...)